# SpeechRecognition not working (microphone not detected)

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, microphone, alsa

I wanted to do an little program with Speech Recognition.

Here is my code (classic one):

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("SAY SOMETHING")
    audio = r.listen(source,timeout=3, phrase_time_limit=3)
    print("TIME OVER")
try:
    print("TEXTE : "+r.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR"))
except Exception:
    print("ERROR")
```

But when I tried to start the program I have this error :

> ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:638:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
>       ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
>       ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
>       ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
>       ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
>       ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
>       ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
>       ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:638:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
>       Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
>       Cannot connect to server request channeljack server is not running or cannot be started
>       JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
>       JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "record.py", line 6, in <module>
>       with sr.Microphone() as source:
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site- 
>       packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 86, in __init__
>       device_info = audio.get_device_info_by_index(device_index) if
>       device_index is not None else audio.get_default_input_device_info()
>       File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 949, in
>       get_default_input_device_info
>       device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
>       IOError: No Default Input Device Available

When I do `arecord -l` I have this :

> **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
>   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC298 Analog [ALC298 Analog]
>     Subdevices: 0/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Ps : The microphone works well with any software like Skype or Google

Comment: From the module documentation: https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/

"As the error says, the program doesn’t know which microphone to use.

To proceed, either use Microphone(device_index=MICROPHONE_INDEX, ...) instead of Microphone(...), or set a default microphone in your OS. You can obtain possible values of MICROPHONE_INDEX using the code in the troubleshooting entry right above this one."

Comment: I already tried this with index 0 to 5 ...

Comment: And how can i set a default microphone on linux ? By only command lines ... i am on fedora 29 (but the thing that's strange is that i can use the microphone on all other apps)

Comment: Have you tried listing the devices to see what's available? `for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))`

Comment: I have 13 device_index i tried all but no one works ... here is the error (same for all) : 
with sr.Microphone(device_index = 13) as source:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 141, in __enter__
    input=True,  # stream is an input stream
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels

Comment: Have all the dependencies installed? `sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev python-all-dev python3-all-dev && sudo pip3 install pyaudio` I'm pretty much out of ideas, some packages take more playing around with than others to get going.

Comment: I did see one closed issue https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/307 referring to "Solved it using Sox", by which I assume they meant they installed Sox https://pypi.org/project/sox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def takecommand():
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, 1)
    print("Listening....")
    speak("listening")
    audio = r.listen(source)


    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"You said: {query}\n ")

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        speak("Could not hear that, Try saying again")

    except sr.RequestError:
        speak("Make Sure that you have a good Internet connection")
    return query
```

You Have to `import pyttsx3` by `pip install pyttsx3` and also `import speech_recognition as sr` by `pip install SpeechRecognition` then your code may work.

Comment: Hello! Please provide some explanation and sources for your answer rather than just posting the code snippet as an answer on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try: Changing your default microphone device.

[image]

Comment: The question states that the microphone works well with other software. Did you see the comment that suggested that the code needed to be told how to pick a microphone to use?

Answer (score 0):

I have a workinng code snippet in one of my project try this it will work possibly:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

rObject = sr.Recognizer() 
audio = '' 
with sr.Microphone() as source: 
    print("Speak...")   
    audio = rObject.listen(source, phrase_time_limit = 0) 
    print("Stop.")
    try: 
        text = rObject.recognize_google(audio, language ='fr-FR') 
        print("You : "+ text)  
    except: 
        speak("Could not understand your audio...PLease try again !")
```

Run this snippet and i think there is some issue of package named PyAudio...is not installed properly and if there is no pyaudio it will not work (specially in python 2.7 it will not work without pyaudio).

Comment: This is only tangentially related to the question

Answer (score 0):

what about adding a Speech_regognition Timeout error in the exception block

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("SAY SOMETHING")
    audio = r.listen(source,timeout=3, phrase_time_limit=3)
    print("TIME OVER")
try:
    print("TEXTE : "+r.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR"))
except sr.WaitTimeoutError:
    print("ERROR")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Installing PyAudio into your code to cut off the error. Even try connecting to the network or make your microphone working.

Comment: This is not how you answer any question here mate. You have to be descriptive.